# Setting "cc" when sending e-mail from Django

Tags: python, django, email, sendmail

Django 1.3 will add a "cc" argument to [`EmailMessage`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage), which is excellent. How would one mimic this using Django 1.2?

First, I tried this:

```
headers = None
if form.cleaned_data['cc_sender']:
    headers = {'Cc': sender} # `cc` argument added in Django 1.3

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, sender, recipients, headers=headers)
msg.attach_alternative(replace(convert(message)), 'text/html')
msg.send(fail_silently=False)
```

This correctly set the "Cc" header but did not actually send the carbon copy. I looked at [SMTP.sendmail](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) for clues, and it appears to take all the recipients as a single argument (it doesn't have separate `to`, `cc`, and `bcc` arguments).

Next I tried this:

```
headers = None
if form.cleaned_data['cc_sender']:
    headers = {'Cc': sender} # `cc` argument added in Django 1.3
    recipients.append(sender) # <-- added this line

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, sender, recipients, headers=headers)
msg.attach_alternative(replace(convert(message)), 'text/html')
msg.send(fail_silently=False)
```

This worked, but meant that when I hit "reply" (in Gmail, at any rate) both addresses appeared in the "To" field. I tried also setting the "Reply-To" header (to `sender`), but this made no difference.

It must be possible to "cc" an address without *also* including the address among the direct recipients. How would I do so?

Comment: If Django correctly set the Cc header, then it seems the problem might be in the mail server, somehow. I think Django doesn't send the messages itself, it just spools them to the mail server.

Comment: Just FYI, the reason `SMTP.sendmail` only takes one list of recipients is because it doesn't care about message headers. SMTP has the "envelope address", which is the person to whom one particular message is going, and the various to/cc headers, which are only used in mail clients (e.g. Thunderbird, Outlook, etc.) to *construct the list* of who will be sent the mail. So when mail is sent, it sends a version with `to` and `cc` intact to the list of people on those lists and a second version to all of the people you'd like to BCC. If this isn't clear, I'll explain further, but I'm out of roooom.

Answer (score 4):

Add the Cc: header just like you did, and additionally pass the list of CC addresses in the "bcc" keyword arg to the EmailMessage constructor.  It seems a little counterintuitive but the real effect of this is simply to add the CC addresses to the recipients list, which is exactly what you want to do.  (If you want to learn more about the difference between headers and the recipient list, the Wikipedia article on SMTP gives some nice background).

```
message = EmailMessage(subject=subject,
                       body=body,
                       from_email=sender,
                       to=to_addresses,
                       bcc=cc_addresses,
                       headers={'Cc': ','.join(cc_addresses)})
message.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a BCC kwarg for EmailMultiAlternatives, I use it in a wrapper function to automatically BCC a records email account on all outbound communications.

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

def _send(to, subject='', text_content='', html_content='', reply_to=None):
    if not isinstance(to, (list, tuple)):
        to = (to,)
    kwargs = dict(
        to=to,
        from_email='%s <%s>' % ('Treatful', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER),
        subject=subject,
        body=text_content,
        alternatives=((html_content, 'text/html'),)
    )
    if reply_to:
        kwargs['headers'] = {'Reply-To': reply_to}
    if not settings.DEBUG:
        kwargs['bcc'] = (settings.RECORDS_EMAIL,)
    message = EmailMultiAlternatives(**kwargs)
    message.send(fail_silently=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

EmailMultiAlternatives is a subclass of [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage). You can specify bcc and cc when you initialise the message.

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to_email], bcc=[bcc_email], cc=[cc_email])
```

Copied from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17064611/5091906)