# send email to bcc and cc in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

views.py

```
if 'send_email' in request.POST:
    subject, from_email, to = 'Parent Incident Notification',user.email, person.parent_email
    html_content = render_to_string('incident/print.html',{'person':person,
                                                                 'report':report,
                                                                  }) 
    text_content = strip_tags(html_content) 
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

The above is the view to send email.By that way i can send the html content along with mail,it is sending the email to [to] address alone ,i want to made another bcc and cc also.I gone through the `Emailmessage objects`  in docs.I don't know how to include the bcc and cc to alter my views.

Need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`EmailMultiAlternatives` is a subclass of [`EmailMessage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage). You can specify `bcc` and `cc` when you initialise the message.

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to_email], bcc=[bcc_email], cc=[cc_email])
```

Comment: We can even add bcc with ```EmailMessage```. For exemple :


```EmailMessage(subject, body, email_from, [email_to], [bcc_email])```

Comment: @Makandianka that’s right, it works with `EmailMessage` as well. I used `EmailMultiAlternatives` in my answer because that’s what the OP was using in their question.

Answer (score 10):

`EmailMessage` now supports `cc` and `bcc`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage

Answer (score 2):

I needed bcc with HTML content as body and here is my implementation

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage(
            'Subject',
            'htmlBody',
            'from@email.com',
            [to@email.com],
            [bcc@email.com],
            reply_to=['reply_to@email.com']
        )
 email.content_subtype = "html"
 email.send(fail_silently=True)
```

For more details refer [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextField

```
class Client(models.Model):
        bcc = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Input multiple emails like this (**bcc** field): test1@example.com,test2@example.com

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

clients= Client.objects.all()
for client in clients:
    subject = client.subject
    content = client.body
    contact_email = client.msg_from
    to = client.msg_to
    bcc_mails = client.bcc
    bcc = bcc_mails.split(",")
    bcc_mails.replace('"', "")
    email = EmailMessage(
        subject,
        content,
        contact_email,
        [to],
        bcc,
        headers={'Reply-To': contact_email}
    )
```